# What does using ZeroMQ in Erlang offer that Erlang already didn't?

Tags: erlang

I'm only passingly familiar with either, but it seems like most of what ZeroMQ offers is already built into Erlang, yet there's an Erlang-ZeroMQ binding that's fairly active according to its [github](https://github.com/zeromq/erlzmq2) page.  What am I missing?

Comment: Suppose you wanted to use Erlang to talk to a system that already uses ZeroMQ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZeroMQ bindings are available for a lot of programming languages, not just Erlang; this is one of the library's great strengths.

Erlang's built-in mechanisms are probably great as long as everything uses Erlang, but I doubt they are in any way compatible with other languages' native networking mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps communication with a ZeroMQ bound but non Erlang process.